# No results from XPath in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, xpath

I am trying to get the result of an XPATH using the code below. Regardless of the actual XPATH expression I use I always get no results.

```
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);

DocumentBuilder builder = null;

builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
doc = builder.parse(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.cdatest02));


NodeList nodes;
String exp = "//versionNumber";  

XPathFactory xfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xfactory.newXPath();

xpath.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceContext() {
    public String getNamespaceURI(String s) {
        if (s.equals(XMLConstants.DEFAULT_NS_PREFIX))
            return doc.lookupNamespaceURI(null);
        else
            return doc.lookupNamespaceURI(s);
    }

    public String getPrefix(String s) {
        return doc.lookupPrefix(s);
    }

    public Iterator getPrefixes(String s) {
        return null;
    }
});


nodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(exp, doc,XPathConstants.NODESET);
Log.i("xpath results", "nothing returned");
```

I suspect the issue has something to do with the namespaces with the XML. The XML has a default namespace declared.

The XML starts off like this (very truncated).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ClinicalDocument xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:npfitlc="NPFIT:HL7:Localisation" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  classCode="DOCCLIN" moodCode="EVN">
    <typeId root="2.16.840.1.113883.1.3" extension="POCD_HD000040"/>
    <npfitlc:messageType root="2.16.840.1.113883.2.1.3.2.4.18.17" extension="POCD_MT000012GB01"/>/
    <id root="A709A442-3CF4-476E-8377-376500E829C9"/>
    <code code="1234567" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.2.1.3.2.4.15"/>
    <title mediaType="text/plain" representation="TXT">Patient Health Record Summary</title>
    <effectiveTime value="201305192000+01"/>
    <confidentialityCode code="V" displayName="very restricted" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.5.25"/>
    <setId root="411910CF-1A76-4330-98FE-C345DDEE5553"/>
    <versionNumber value="1"/>
    .... lots more lines of XML ...,
```

Any thoughts on where I am going wrong?

Comment: Strange - there was a correct answer here a few minutes ago and now it has gone...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XPath, unfortunately, has no concept of default namespaces. To search a namespaced document, you must use namespace prefixes in your XPath syntax, and bind the prefixes to the appropriate namespace name. If the source document used default namespaces you probably can't pick up that binding from the context, so you'll have to provide it pogrammatically.